# How To Run JAR Application On NOKIA 6030?

Tags: netbeans, java-me, midp

I have a problem. I make an application in MIDP and then run it in wtk 2.2 it runs perfectly but when I use datacable and install the application using jad and jar on the mobile (NOKIA 6030); the application does not open. Can anyone help me on this?
Mobile Error = "invilied application delete this application?"

Comment: use jar only for installation.

Comment: both jad & jar, now problem is solved friends thank you all

Comment: Walikumasalam,ya its possible,attach listener to textboxes and when you selected that time add command "Send" and get entered string from seleccted textbox and send it. check this my blog link to send sms http://dilchahtahay.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/how-to-send-text-sms-in-j2me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just open your project in `Netbeans`, right click on project & select properties. In left side select Second Option "PlatForm" and now in Right side change the version of `MIDP` Verion to 2.0 your problem will be solved.  By Default `NetBeans` uses `Midp-2.1` Version so this error is very common.